# getting an error when trying to invoke variable which is assigned to function

Tags: ios, swift, function, variables, swift2

In playground, I am creating a simple class :

```
class myClass {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    var placeHolder = myfunc

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    func  myfunc(string: String) -> String {
        print("you passed \(string)")

        return " "
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
```

I'm calling `myFunc` using variable named `placeHolder` by doing

```
test!.placeHolder("this is a test")
```

However, I'm getting this error

```
cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'myClass'
```

However, if I remove `var placeHolder = myfunc` away from `myClass` and doing this

```
class myClass {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    // Remove this line
    // var placeHolder = myfunc

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    func  myfunc(string: String) -> String {
        print("you passed \(string)")

        return ""
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}

var test: myClass? = myClass(name: "p", text: "hello, world")

let placeHoder = test!.myfunc
placeHoder("this is test")
```

it will work

I dont really understand why I have to pass `myClass` object as an argument instead of string in the first case. Does anyone have any ideas about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `placeHolder` you will see its type:

```
var placeHolder: (myClass) -> (String) -> String
```

That means, that if you give `placeHolder` an instance of `myClass`, it will return a function of type `(String) -> String`.

This is how instance methods are called on objects.  You call the function by providing an instance of the object.

Normally you would call `myFunc` like this:

```
test!.myfunc("this is a test")
```

but this is equivalent to:

```
myClass.myfunc(test!)("this is a test")
```

So, you could use `placeHolder` like this:

```
test!.placeHolder(test!)("this is a test")
```

---

If you make `myfunc` a `static` function:

```
static func myfunc(string: String) -> String {
    print("you passed \(string)")

    return ""
}
```

and then change `placeHolder` to refer to it:

```
var placeHolder = myClass.myfunc
```

then you could call it like this:

```
test!.placeHolder("this is a test")
```

because as a `static func`, you don't provide an instance to call the function.

Comment: `myClass.myfunc(test!)("this is a test")` sounds like curry function, doesn't it ?

Comment: It looks like the call to a curried function, but it isn't really.  This works in Swift 3 where the curry function syntax has been removed.